# Fourier series of $\sqrt[3]{\sin x}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

So I've done some experiments with how to add distortion to audio, and one of the methods I'm proposing is to take the cube root of an audio signal as a way to add overdrive. As the waveform that you're supposed to start with is a sine wave, I decided to tackle the problem of finding the magnitudes of the harmonics for $\sqrt[3]{\sin\left(2\pi fx\right)}$.

Based on what I've read about Fourier transforms, the coefficient of $\sin\left(nx\right)$ for $\sqrt[3]{\sin x}$is:

$\displaystyle a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\sin\left(nx\right)\sqrt[3]{\sin x}\,dx$

Since $\sqrt[3]{\sin x}$ contains only odd harmonics, I calculated the values of $a_n$ for odd *n.* Here's what I got out of the first seven terms:

$\displaystyle\left\{a_{1}, a_{3}, a_{5}, a_{7}, a_{9}, a_{11}, a_{13}\right\}=\frac{3\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}}{4\pi^{2}\sqrt[3]{2}}\left\{1, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{10}, \frac{7}{110}, \frac{1}{22}, \frac{13}{374}, \frac{26}{935}\right\}$

which leads to the following:

$a_{2n+1}=\displaystyle\left(\frac{3\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{3}}{4\pi^{2}\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)_{n}}\qquad n\geqslant 0,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}$

where $\left(a\right)_{q}$ is the Pochhammer symbol.

Putting this all together, I get:

$\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{\sin\left(2\pi fx\right)}=\frac{2\pi^2\sqrt[3]{2}}{3\operatorname{\Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3}\sum_{n\geqslant 0,\,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)_{n}}\,\sin\left(\left(4n+2\right)\pi fx\right)\right)$

Is this correct?

EDIT: By "cube root", I am referring to the real solution, where $\sqrt[3]{-x}=-\sqrt[3]{x}$ for $x\geqslant 0$.

Comment: Notice that your function is not well defined for negative $x$. Hint: Try to solve the problem with the related function $|\sin(x)|^\frac{1}{3}$ which is defined in the range $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$, and try to to calculate the integral for the Fourier coefficients $c(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin(x)|^\frac{1}{3} e^{-i k x}\;dy$. This is possible in terms of the $\Gamma$-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is straighforward, and I'm going to present it here with a minor generalisation.

Remember that the Fourier series to order $n$ of a function $f(x)$ is defined as

$$f_s(x,n) = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}c(k) e^{i k x}\tag{1a}$$

where the Fourier coefficients are defined as

$$c(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-i k x}\;dx\tag{1b}$$

It is more convenient to consider the related function

$$f(x) = |\sin(x)|^a\tag{2}$$

which is defined in the range $-\pi \lt x \lt \pi$.

Here we have introduced a paramter $a \gt -1$ which can be set to $\frac{1}{3}$ in the end.

The integral for the Fourier coefficient can be done in closed form:

$$c(k) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\sin(x)|^a e^{-i k x}\;dx = 2^{-a} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right) \binom{a}{\frac{k+a}{2}}\tag{3}$$

Notice that $c(k)$ vanishes for odd $k$.

The Fourier series then become

$$f_s(x,n) = c(0) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n} c(k) \cos(k x)\tag{4}$$

For the first few orders $n$ these are

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2^{-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a}{2}} \\
 2 & 2^{-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a}{2}}-2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+2}{2}} \cos (2 x) \\
 4 & 2^{-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a}{2}}-2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+2}{2}} \cos (2 x)+2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+4}{2}} \cos (4 x) \\
 6 & 2^{-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a}{2}}-2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+2}{2}} \cos (2 x)+2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+4}{2}} \cos (4 x)\\
&-2^{1-a} \binom{a}{\frac{a+6}{2}} \cos (6 x) \\
\end{array}
\right)
\tag{5}$$

The approximations are shown in the graph

[image]

Notice that for odd $n \ge 1$ we have $f_s(x,n) = f_s(n-1,x)$

We can also let $n$ go to infinity in $(4)$ which results in a representation of our function in terms of a hypergeometric function:

$$\begin{align} |\sin(x)|^{a}  =2^{-a} \binom{a} {\frac{a}{2}} \left(-1+\\2 \Re\left(\, _2F_1\left(1,-\frac{a}{2};\frac{a}{2}+1;e^{-2 i x}\right)\right)\right)
\end{align}\tag{5}$$